# Django: Adding default values to ModelForms

Tags: django

I am working on a small project in django and I am trying to take a form that is filled out by the user and store it in the database. For the form, I am using the ModelForm instead of the standard Form.

The user submits the form with the name and description of the group that the form creates. I want to add default values to the form values in the model before I have the new object into the daatabase.

Here is the Form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from tab.models import Group

member_count_choices = (('bronze', '1-4',),
                        ('silver', '5-7',),
                        ('gold', '8-10',),
                        ('platnium', '11+',))

class CreateGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.db import transaction

from .models import Group, User
from .forms import CreateGroupForm, AddMembersFour, AddMembersSeven
from .forms import AddMembersTen, AddMembersEleven

# the following def is going to be what grabs all of the different groups that
# are in the database
# filters can be added later

def groups(request):
    # following is all of th actions that are taken after the form is submitted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        createGroup = CreateGroupForm(request.POST)
        if createGroup.is_valid():
            cd = createGroup.cleaned_data
            groupName = cd['name']
            groupDescription = cd['description']
            groupDefaultLevel = 1
            groupDefaultStatus = 1
            groupDefaultCreatedBy = User.objects.get(username='omar')
            new_group = createGroup
            new_group.name = groupName
            new_group.description = groupDescription
            new_group.levels = groupDefaultLevel
            new_group.status = groupDefaultStatus
            new_group.created_by = groupDefaultCreatedBy
            new_group.save()
            return redirect('/tab/addMembers')
```

Here is the Models.py file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    levels = models.SmallIntegerField()
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see. I am trying to add the default values for the group model's levels, status, created_by, and create. The created_by is a random user that i created from the admin site.

Here is what the local site says:

```
IntegrityError at /tab/createGroup/
NOT NULL constraint failed: tab_group.levels
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/tab/createGroup/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: tab_group.levels
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 20 Jun 2017 23:03:09 +0000
```

So I just need to know how to add default values to the form before it is saved into the database. Can anyone help me

Comment: I have not used `ModelForm`, so there may be a more a native way to do it with that module, but I do know you can add `default=""` values to your model itself. IE, for `Group.levels` you could set in your model to: `models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)`, would set the default value to 1 for any instantiated objects for which a levels value was not otherwise provided. Have you tried using default in your models? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using model form, you can set default value of your fields model. it will looks like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
  description = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank=True)
  levels = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
  status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True
```